# How to concat string and add html tag to it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have string something like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, #consectetur and #adipiscing
```

I want to add html tag for hashtags which are present in the string.
Expected Output is:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="/users/tag/consectetur">#consectetur</a> and <a href="/users/tag/adipiscing">#adipiscing</a>
```

I am using javascript string operator split() and join(), but I am not getting the expected output.

```
    const string =  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, #consectetur and #adipiscing" 
    
    function addHtmlTag(string){
       string = string.split("#").join('<a href="#/users/tag/">#</a>');
    return string
    }
console.log(addHtmlTag(string))
```

What will be the changes for adding html tag?

Comment: Probably you're not getting the expected output because the code crashes at `const string =  Lorem ipsum` ? This is a syntax error

Comment: @JeremyThille I forgot to give "" in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
const str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, #consectetur and #adipiscing"

const replacedStr = str.split(" ").map(word => (
  word[0] === "#" ? `<a href="/users/tag/${word.split("#")[1]}">${word}</a>` : word
)).join(" ")

console.log(replacedStr)
```

This searches for words that starts with `"#"` and append the `a` tag based on the word.

Comment: I always like your answers! Tricky!!! :)

Comment: Always glad to hear that man, thanks!

Comment: @SinanYaman That's the most elegant code I've ever seen :)

Answer (score 2):

It can replace with regexp

```js
    const str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, #consectetur and #adipiscing'
    const result = str.replace(/#(\w+)\b/g, '<a href="/users/tag/$1">#$1</a>')
    
    console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed Double qutes ("")

```
const string =  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, #consectetur and #adipiscing"
```

Comment: I guess that was just a copy paste error.